# Annual revenue throws error : "Illegal Integer" with char 1000000000 and above

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforcedx

In my below code I am getting error as Illegal integer.

```
public void refedgeAnnualrevenue(list<Account> newAccts){
        for(Account ac : newAccts){
            if(ac.AnnualRevenue >= 0 && ac.AnnualRevenue <=49999999){
                ac.RefEdge_Annual_Revenue__c ='< $50M';
            } else if(ac.AnnualRevenue >= 50000000 && ac.AnnualRevenue <=499999999){
                ac.RefEdge_Annual_Revenue__c ='$50M-$500M';
            }else if(ac.AnnualRevenue >= 500000000 && ac.AnnualRevenue <=999999999){
                ac.RefEdge_Annual_Revenue__c ='$500M - $1B';
            }else if(ac.AnnualRevenue >= 1000000000  && ac.AnnualRevenue <=4999999999){
               ac.RefEdge_Annual_Revenue__c= '$1B - $5B';
            }else if(ac.AnnualRevenue >= 5000000000){
                ac.RefEdge_Annual_Revenue__c ='> $5B';
            }
        } 
    }
```

at the last two if else only.

Please help to fix this issue.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Account.AnnualRevenue` is soaptype: `xsd:double` and is a field of type Currency with precision (18,0).  Normally, in Apex one would treat these as Decimals so you would have:

```
public void refedgeAnnualrevenue(list<Account> newAccts){
        for(Account ac : newAccts){
            if(ac.AnnualRevenue >= 0 && ac.AnnualRevenue <=49999999.0){
                ac.RefEdge_Annual_Revenue__c ='< $50M';
            } else if(ac.AnnualRevenue >= 50000000.0 && ac.AnnualRevenue <=499999999.0){
                ac.RefEdge_Annual_Revenue__c ='$50M-$500M';
            }else if(ac.AnnualRevenue >= 500000000.0 && ac.AnnualRevenue <=999999999.0){
                ac.RefEdge_Annual_Revenue__c ='$500M - $1B';
            }else if(ac.AnnualRevenue >= 1000000000.0  && ac.AnnualRevenue <=4999999999.0){
               ac.RefEdge_Annual_Revenue__c= '$1B - $5B';
            }else if(ac.AnnualRevenue >= 5000000000.0){
                ac.RefEdge_Annual_Revenue__c ='> $5B';
            }
        } 
    }
```

So, the comparand should be expressed as a decimal constant (adding the `.0` to the integer in your OP).

Integers are limited in magnitude to `+/- 2,147,483,647` (i.e. `2E31 -1`)

Answer (score 1):

Your AnnualRevenue overflows Integer data type, just add `L` after your integers in if-clauses like this, it will automatically cast them to Long:

```
if (ac.AnnualRevenue >= 1000000000L && ac.AnnualRevenue <= 4999999999L)
```

Note: add `L` to all integers in comparison.